# How to dynamically switch jinja filter

Tags: html, flask, jinja2, forex, python-babel

I am currently making a web app that displays a list of transactions of the user. I want to make a setting to change the currency from USD to EUR. I am using custom filter in jinja:

My custom filter and function:

```
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
from babel.numbers import format_currency

c = CurrencyRates()

# Format and convert transaction amount in EUR
def to_euros(value):
    value = c.convert('USD', 'EUR', value)
    return format_currency(value, 'EUR', locale='en_US')
app.jinja_env.filters['to_euros'] = to_euros

# Format transaction amount in USD
def to_usd(value):
    value = c.convert('USD', 'USD', value)
    return format_currency(value, 'USD', locale='en_US')
app.jinja_env.filters['to_usd'] = to_usd
```

My routes.py:

```
@app.route("/history", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def history():
    # Getting all transactions linked to user id
    row = Transactions.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user.id).order_by(Transactions.date.desc())
    return rnd_tmp("history.html", rows=row)
```

And in my html file:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title%}
    History
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <div id="body-main">
        <table class="table table-striped table-full">
            <thead>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Notes</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for row in rows %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ row['date'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row['type'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row['category'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row['amount'] | to_usd }}</td>
                        <td>{{ row['notes'] }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I want to make a new route that has a select option to change between USD and EUR currency, so changing from `<td>{{ row['amount'] | to_usd }}</td>` to `<td>{{ row['amount'] | to_euros }}</td>`.
How can I do that dynamically using Flask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jinja filters can take arguments - see the [documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#filters). This means that you can write a more generic `to_currency` filter that can take the selected currency as a parameter.

For example:

```
def to_currency(value, code):
    value = c.convert('USD', code, value)
    return format_currency(value, code, locale='en_US')

app.jinja_env.filters['to_currency'] = to_currency
```

And you would use it in the following manner in a Jinja template:

```
<td>{{ row['amount'] | to_currency(selected_currency) }}</td>
```

The string value `selected_currency` would be passed in from the route either as `'USD'` or `'EUR'`.

See diagram below showing where the left side of the filter 'the value' gets passed into the Python function along with the filter's arguments:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I am quite confused how jinja filters take arguments, so if you can clarify, it takes the second argument and so forth, but not the first argument, since that is what the filter is being applied to?

Comment: @aNdroid - I've added an image. Hopefully this clarifies the position of a filter's value, i.e. the left side of the pipe (|), in relation to its Python method arguments.